# VIMRC, SCREENRC, BASHRC, KSHRC, etc. What does the "RC" mean?

Tags: linux

In these and other applications what does the "RC" stand for?

Comment: +1 I was just going to ask the same question. I recently installed freebsd and I started wonder about many files ending with `rc`.

Comment: Some RC files from JS world - [What are `rc` files in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36212256/465053)

Comment: Related posts - [What does rc, in bashrc, nanorc stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23482/605028) & [What does “rc” in .bashrc stand for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3467/221891)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's a bit of interesting historical perspective about its derivation on [this page](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part1/section-3.html):

> "rc" derives from "runcom", from the MIT CTSS system, ca. 1965.

and that

> "rc" in Unix is a fossil from that usage.'

Answer (score 32):

It stands for `Run Commands`

And as the name already says it can contain a listing of commands to run.
For example in a xinitrc file
You can list commands to run when initializing X. so you can make a Xterm window popup, or load GDM/Gnome.

Comment: Although, this isn't always the case, for example, Gimp stores it's configuration files in files named colorrc, contextrc, controllerrc, etc.

Answer (score 13):

It stands for `Run Commands`.