# What is the full name of rc file? e.g. bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Say`vimrc`or `screenrc`, what does the `rc` mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/144339/sayvimrcor-screenrc-what-does-the-rc-mean)

There are lots of rc file inside linux?

.bashrc
.vimrc
.gvimrc
etc etc

I am curious what does rc mean?
I can't find any information in google or wiki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file):

> The "rc" naming convention of "rc files" was inspired by the "runcom" facility mentioned above and does not stand for "resource configuration" or "runtime configuration" as is often wrongly guessed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdr.html), 'rc' stands for 'run commands'.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23482/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-nanorc-stand-for